# Firefox add-ons where to find .xpi files

Tags: linux, firefox, ubuntu, browser, firefox-addon

As you install some add-on to firefox browser, where can I find the .xpi file in a linux platform.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Press the Alt key to show the menu, click on "Help" then "Troubleshooting Information" then in the page that opens up click on the button that says "Show Folder" its in the "profile folder" row. Then click on the folder called extensions.

Comment: I actually like this answer more than my own since it works on all platforms. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Add-ons are located in `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/extensions`